# How to use ServiceStack OpenApiFeature/Swagger with api description and response examples?

Tags: servicestack, swagger-ui, openapi

Is there a way to add a description to the api (not just to individual routes) and update api version and add example responses/resquests using the OpenApiFeature in ServiceStack? I can't find anything in the documentation about these pieces of the swagger ui.

I tried using the Api attribute to add the description but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only [declarative Attributes that can annotate individual Services](https://docs.servicestack.net/openapi#open-api-attributes) are documented on the Open API docs. Here's a fully annotated example:

```
[Tag("TheTag")]
[Api("SwaggerTest Service Description")]
[ApiResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Your request was not understood")]
[ApiResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Oops, something broke")]
[Route("/swagger", "GET", Summary = @"GET / Summary", Notes = "GET / Notes")]
[Route("/swagger/{Name}", "GET", Summary = @"GET Summary", Notes = "GET /Name Notes")]
[Route("/swagger/{Name}", "POST", Summary = @"POST Summary", Notes = "POST /Name Notes")]
public class SwaggerExample
{
    [ApiMember(Description = "Color Description",
               ParameterType = "path", DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
    [ApiAllowableValues("Name", typeof(MyColor))] //Enum
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ApiMember]
    [ApiAllowableValues("Color", typeof(MyColor))] //Enum
    public MyColor Color { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "Aliased Description", DataType="string", IsRequired=true)]
    [DataMember(Name = "Aliased")]
    public string Original { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "Not Aliased", DataType="string", IsRequired=true)]
    public string NotAliased { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(IsRequired = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public DateTime[] MyDateBetween { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "Nested model 1", DataType = "SwaggerNestedModel")]
    public SwaggerNestedModel NestedModel1 { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "Nested model 2", DataType = "SwaggerNestedModel2")]
    public SwaggerNestedModel2 NestedModel2 { get; set; }
}
```

The other annotation Open API allows is [grouping logical operations by Tag](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/grouping-operations-with-tags/) which you would use annotate in ServiceStack with the `[Tag]` attribute that you can then provide a description for when registering the `OpenApiFeature` Plugin, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new OpenApiFeature
{
    Tags =
    {
        new OpenApiTag
        {
            Name = "TheTag",
            Description = "TheTag Description",
            ExternalDocs = new OpenApiExternalDocumentation
            {
                Description = "Link to External Docs Desc",
                Url = "http://example.org/docs/path",
            }
        }
    }
});
```